# Photon absorbtion and reemission in water vapor

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, laser

The real question:

Water vapor absorbs photons at 950nm -- does that mean that it reemits a photon at 950nm later, or does it heat up, emit photons at a longer wavelength, or what?

The "I'm curious" question:

I know that in general, if a gas has an absorption line when it's cold, it has an emission line at the same wavelength when it's hot.  And that some materials will absorb photons at some wavelength and emit longer-wave photons (i.e., florescence or under the right conditions with some materials, lasing).

Are there any general rules about what happens when a photon at a certain wavelength is absorbed?  When an atom or molecule absorbs a photon and becomes excited does it ever reemit a photon at that wavelength?  Never does it?  It depends on the material?

Comment: Hi, just to point out that this question as many questions/concepts behind it and it might put off many people that could answer maybe one of them, or all of them, due to the amount of "teaching" needed. In general the redistribution of energy in a material/molecule follows quantum mechanics (selection rules) and what is "easier" for the electrons to go to a more "relaxed" state. Then the band/energy structure of the material will dictate lifetimes and types of transitions.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to refine the question so I get an answer, especially to the first part, which seems to be amenable to a yes/no answer?